# What does ret mean here and how the value is set

Tags: python

read some source code as below:

```
class Solution(object):
    def myAtoi(self, s):
        """
        :type str: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        ###better to do strip before sanity check (although 8ms slower):
        #ls = list(s.strip())
        #if len(ls) == 0 : return 0
        if len(s) == 0 : return 0
        ls = list(s.strip())

        sign = -1 if ls[0] == '-' else 1
        if ls[0] in ['-','+'] : del ls[0]
        ret, i = 0, 0
        while i < len(ls) and ls[i].isdigit() :
          ret = ret*10 + ord(ls[i]) - ord('0')
        i += 1
    return max(-2**31, min(sign * ret,2**31-1))
```

what does`ret,i=0,0` means, can not find a method called ret in python.

Comment: the question is what does ' ret, i=0, 0' means

Comment: as per this code `ret` is user defined variable which have 0 initially. what is issue in this?

Comment: ah, i see, didn't notice python can instanitate multi variables in this way, was confused thought ret is a method or function

Answer (score 0):

```
ret,i=0,0
```

Means, you are initializing ret as 0 and i as 0 in one statement.

if it was

```
ret,i=0,10
```

This would have meant, ret would initialize to 0, while i would get initialize as 10.